# is AMP not compatible with CSS Grid / Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid, amp-html

Just done a new lightweight responsive html website in CSS Grid with a bit of flexbox - working perfectly.

Converted a test page (with a bit of everything in it) to AMP, validated in Google DevTools.

Woo-Hoo me thinks - until I look at the page in a couple of browsers.

Content all present but certainly not correct - all the 'grid-template-areas' jumbled up.

Removed all the AMP stuff and page displays perfectly.

Any comments please?  Can't provide a link as the site is still local.

Thank you.

I'll try again but without the named 'grid-template-areas'.

Should have realised that it was going uncommonly well :-)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.